# Как получить логарифм от А в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вопрос заключается в том что мне нужно узнать как выводить логарифм от А? Какой для этого модуль необходим?

Answer (score 1):

Модуль `math`. Функция `math.log(X, [base])` - логарифм `X` по основанию `base`. Если `base` не указан, вычисляется натуральный логарифм.